# ASP.NET User Control with JQuery Plugin

Tags: asp.net

I would like to create a masked textbox (user control) using a jquery plugin but I want to send parameters from my aspx page to my ascx file in order to call a javascript function which has parameters like the mask, the placeholder, etc ...

This is my line of code in my aspx page :

```
<UC:MaskedTextBox runat="server" ID="MaskedTextBox1" Mask="9999" Placeholder="_" Text="1234" />
```

This is what I have in my asxs file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {CreateMaskedTextBox('" + _Id + "', '" + _Mask + "', '" + _Placeholder + "', '" + _Text + "');});
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="MaskedTextBox_TextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

How can i get the id, mask, placeholder that I have initialized in the aspx page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare properties in the code behind like this:

```
public string PlaceHolder { get; set; }
```

Do it for each parameter you need.
You can check this question too:
[Pass data from a ASP.NET page to ASCX user controls loaded dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201312/pass-data-from-a-asp-net-page-to-ascx-user-controls-loaded-dynamically)

Comment: It worked, i then accessed the properties like this in the ascx file : <%= Placeholder %>